# Open two arguments from command line in C

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

How would I go about opening only two files from the command line in C? I am working on a Machine Learning Project where the first file has the training data (train.txt) and the second file has the actual data (data.txt). For example, when I compile I am looking for something like this:

./machineLearning train.txt data.txt

Initially, I was thinking it would be something along these lines but was not quite sure if this made sense:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char fileName[100];

    while(argc < 2)
    {
        FILE* fp;
        fp = fopen(fileName, "r"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You find the command line arguments in `argv`. The first argument is a string at `argv[1]` and the second at `argv[2]`. So (after checking `argc` that you have indeed gotten two arguments), just pass these strings to fopen to open the files:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file1;
    FILE *file2;
    if (argc < 3) {
        /* report that not enough arguments have been given and exit */
    }
    file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    file2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    /* Check whether file1 or file2 are 0, in case either file could not be opened,
       then use the file streams as you require. */
}
```